# google-api-java-client android get events from google calendar

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I am trying to access google calendar in android .. I am using google java client api (gdata api not working in android.. tried a lot.. some issue with library )..
What i received were list of calendar, not events. So I want to access events within a specific date range.. say I want to retrieve all the events inbetween date range 3-march-2011 to 5 march 2011 Can anyone tell me how to do that ?

I am using the following example at
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/calendar-v2-atom-android-sample/?repo=samples&r=f1e31c6861e04679c450e36531cf7b3bcc96ed74

Comment: please help me to figure out it

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `calendar-android-sample` from `google-api-java-client`,

Here they have given the example for accessing the Calendars. If you want to access events then you need the `calendar-id`. To get that,

In your project `src` you will find a class named `CalendarSampleActivity.java`. In this there is a method called `refreshView()`. In which they have created the list of Calendars associated with that account by populating data as `calendarInfo.summary`. You can get id by `calendarInfo.id`.

Now there is a class named `AsyncLoadCalendars.java`. Copy it into same destination and name it as `AsyncLoadEvents.java`. In that just replace

```
CalendarList feed = client.calendarList().list().setFields(CalendarInfo.FEED_FIELDS).execute();
model.reset(feed.getItems());
```

by

```
Events events = client.events().list("calendar_id").execute(); //Pass calendar_id as parameter
```

Here you have to the pass `calendar_id` that we obtained previously. Now Call this method properly. You will get the list of all the events in JSON formate. Just parse it and get neccessary data.